# Can't resolve all parameters for anything:

Tags: angular, typescript

For whatever reason I cannot automatically resolve anything in the constructor of services, components, ect. I have other projects that don't have this problem.

For example a component with the following constructor:

```
constructor(
    private location: Location
) {
```

results in the following error: `Can't resolve all parameters for SearchQueryComponent: (?).`

As a workaround I've been doing the following:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => Location)) private location: Location
) {
```

What am I missing? Every other project I've worked on in angular does not require the decorators to resolve injectables.

My `tsproject.json` does have `experimentalDecorators` and `emitDecoratorMetadata` set to true.

polyfills.ts:

```
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Comment: Where did you import the Location class from? Is it an Angular service?

Comment: have you imported `import {Location} from '@angular/common';` before injecting

Comment: @Vikas Yes; exactly how you have it.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes; from  `'@angular/common'`

Comment: Its worth noteing that `Location` was just an example. Injection only works when using `@Inject(forwardRef(()`...

Comment: @ChadCarisch Has it been added to the providers array (either at the module level or the component level)?

Comment: It's included as part of the router module. Add `RouterModule.forRoot([])` to your module imports, and the Locations ervice will be available: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krgjxs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsearch-query.component.ts

Comment: @JBNizet I have that in my Module. Remember it works when using `@Inject(forwardRef(() => Location))`. Its not just `Location`. I could have used `Injector` as my example.

Comment: You'll need to post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. It's impossible to figure out what is wrong with the two lines of code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after reviewing the example provided by @jb-nizet. Found that the `import './polyfills';` was not imported first in the `main.ts` file.

Changed `main.ts` from:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import './polyfills';
```

to

```
import './polyfills';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
```

Everything works!

Comment: Glad you found the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. it was a frustrating problem.

Comment: Just curious: don't you use the Angular CLI? It would do the right thing automatically.

Comment: For this project I used the CLI. But normally I don't. It looks like my linter was set to format on save, and it kept reorganizing the import statements.